# Deploy pods on master node

Tags: kubernetes

I have a native Kubernetes v1.28.5 cluster running with 2 nodes: control plane and work node.
Currently I can deploy pods only on worker node. How I can deploy pods also on control plane. Most of the time the server is almost idle. I want to use it also like a work node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't recommended for security reasons, but if it's just for testing you can do this by running the following kubectl command, which removes the control-plane taint for the master node and that allows normal workloads to run there.

```
kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane-
```

Source https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/

Answer (score 0):

By default, Kubernetes does not schedule user pods on master nodes. Master nodes in a Kubernetes cluster are dedicated to managing the cluster itself, including components like the API server, scheduler, controller manager, and etcd. Allowing user pods to run on master nodes could potentially disrupt the management and stability of the cluster.

if you want to first you can use [node selector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-pods-nodes/), also remove taints from master node. you'll find the taint something like `node-role.kubernetes.io/master-`

Comment: What configuration I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Deploying a pod on master node is generally discourage being security and reliability reason. The role of master node is to manage cluster's resources and ideally shouldn't be use to run the pods/workload.